# Typescript: Omit does not warning for extra props

Tags: typescript, interface

I have a problem with `Omit`. It is not complaining about extra props.
Take a look to this sample code:

```js
interface Model {
   prop:number;
   dangerProp: number;
}

interface SafeModel extends Omit<Model, "dangerProp"> {}
```

This works as expected, however if a change `SafeModel` to this:

```js
interface SafeModel extends Omit<Model, "dangerPropMisspeled"> {}
```

There is no error anywhere despite that prop does not exits. `Pick` always check for a correlation, but `Omit` seems not to, but it is not an option on my real code.

This is bothering me, if someone change `Model` without being notice that `SafeModel` should be change to, it could lead me to some bugs in the factories or somewhere else.

So, is there any way to force `Omit` to check for a correlation? An eslint solution would be a valid workaround for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects I use set of overridden utils that works as i need.
My version of `Omit` looks like this. Hope it helps you. Look below or test in [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=11&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgrgZ2AewLYHlUEtgB4AqANFANJQQAewEAdgCYJQDWEIyAZlPgHxQC8UAApYAxkwLEAohREAbOHQi4WbTkVLduAKC1Ya1AE7sAhiOgBZZItlQA3lqiOwB5GABcNOKgBGEAwG4HRzpjGgBzP0EXdyhPHz9AgF8dPUMTMygAZWN2CEtrcipaBlhEFAxsPHyIWWIAIhDwyOi63ltk3X0-dOhs3OqbSmp6RngkNEwcXAH6xoiDKNdzLAQESFkIOla7ZKA)

```
type CustomOmit<T, K extends keyof T> = Pick<T, Exclude<keyof T, K>>

interface Model {
   prop:number;
   dangerProp: number;
}

interface SafeModel extends CustomOmit<Model, "dangerProp"> {}

interface SafeModel extends CustomOmit<Model, "dangerPropMisspeled"> {}
```

[image]

Has to work for [TS 2.8](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#predefined-conditional-types) and above. Release where `Exclude` was introduced

---

Please, let me know if it works or not )

Comment: Works like a charm :) Very thanks for the help ^^ I can accept the answer in a couple of minutes